# How can I add button for each block of data

Tags: reactjs

```
App.js-

class App extends Component{
render(){
const data= [
{
id: 1,
name: "John Smith",
email: "jsmith@test.com",
phone: "123456789"
}, 
{
id: 2,
name: "ABCD",
email: "abcd@test.com",
phone: "987654321"
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Tyrion",
email: "tyrion@test.com",
phone: "123412345"
},
];
return(
<div >
<Customers data={data}  />
</div>
)
}
}
export default App;


Customer.js-

class Customers extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {
}
}
handleclick= (event)=>{
this.setState(alert("button clicked"))
console.log("button clicked")
}
render(){
const data=this.props.data
const newdata = data.map( (cval) => {
return(
<div>
<h1>{cval.name}</h1>
<p>{cval.email}</p>
{cval.phone}
</div>
)
})
return(
       
<div>
<button type="submit" onClick={this.handleclick} >click to view details</button>
{newdata}
</div>
)
}
}
export default Customers;
```

I want to add button after each persons data like in this case (I want to add button after each person's name, email and phone number) so how can I do that? Here I have created a button (click view details) but it is appearing on top of persons details. So how can I put this button after each persons data.

Comment: To do so you need to add the button inside your map function to render a button after each person's detail instead of having them separately, something like this:
const Customers = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((cval) => (
        <>
          <div>
            <h1>{cval.name}</h1>
            <p>{cval.email}</p>
            {cval.phone}
          </div>
          <button>Click Here</button>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach,

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John Smith",
        email: "jsmith@test.com",
        phone: "123456789"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "ABCD",
        email: "abcd@test.com",
        phone: "987654321"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Tyrion",
        email: "tyrion@test.com",
        phone: "123412345"
      }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <Customers data={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

class Customers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  handleclick = (event) => {
    this.setState(alert("button clicked"));
    console.log("button clicked");
  };
  render() {
    const data = this.props.data;
    const newdata = data.map((cval) => {
      return (
        <div class="panel">
          <h1>{cval.name}</h1>
          <p>{cval.email}</p>
          {cval.phone}
          <div>
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleclick}>
              click to view details
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return <div>{newdata}</div>;
  }
}
```

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-knuth-bqfrg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: one thing i want to ask is what is the purpose of passing id in this  this.handleclick(cval.id) given in the above link(codesandbox).

Comment: In case you need to show more info about the user on click of the button